# Corrupt Photos Libray when migrating to new Photos.app

Tags: photos.app

I've downloaded the new Photos.app and migrated my iPhoto Library and now all my full screen images are replaced by a grey exclamation mark.

This is being logged in the console :

```
14/04/2015 22:48:04,002 Photos[1373]: Unsupported item: IMG_0694.JPG of type 0`
14/04/2015 22:48:04,029 Photos[1373]: Unknown version type: RDVersion(0x600003530860) modelId=23946 uuid=134LStKnROWcZ51vzo+yGg
tableName=RKVersion state=persisted,readonly,local, IMG_0694.JPG 0
```

Does someone as any idea how to fix this ?

If I explore the package of my Library the Masters folder contains all my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Photos is so new, it may be tricky to find solutions to issues.  However, applying iPhoto type fixes may help.

Before beginning and repair, make sure you have a backup of your entire Photos/iPhoto library.

1. You can try closing Photos, then open Photos while pressing Command and Option.  This brings up a window for repairing issues.  Select the Repair option to start rebuilding the library.  These instructions can also be found [HERE on Apple's website](https://help.apple.com/photos/mac/1.0/?lang=en#/pht6be18f93).
2. Unfortunately, the wonderful app, iPhoto Library Manager doesn't support Photos.app, but they are creating a new app that does, call [PowerPhotos](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/comments/announcing_powerphotos)!  Hopefully it'll be released soon.  Until then, we must rely on Apples built in repair functions.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to repair the library without success, I guess I'll have to wait for PowerPhotos then